# Deploying a WCF service to IIS 6

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, iis, deployment, web-config

I created a wcf service using VS2010 and it works correctly, when I run it from VS2010, but when I deploy it on IIS 6(according [this](http://softwareandfinanceforums.com/index.php?topic=233.0) post), It does not work.

I did this steps:

1. I created a folder in my server(`C:\WCFServices\HRService`) and copied `HRService.svc` and web.config to it and grant full access to this folder for `ASPNET` user.
2. I created a `Bin` folder in the above folder and copied my service dll in it.
3. I Created new virtual directory in my default web site(`HR`):

[image]

My `.svc` files , web.Configs are as below:

My `.svc` file

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="HumanResourceService.HRService" %>
```

And my `web.Config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="HumanResourceService.HRService">
  <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="" contract="HumanResourceService.IHRService" >
     <identity>
       <dns value="localhost"/>
     </identity>
  </endpoint>
 <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
 </service>
 </services>
 <behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior>
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
   </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But when I want to access my WCF service via IE I get this error:
[image]

Could anyone tell me, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
In IIS and in **Web Service Extensions** section, the `ASP.NET V4.0.30319` status was **Prohibited** and I changed it to **Allowed** and the problem solved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the the name for the service in the configuration file matches the .svc file.  In your posted code it doesn't.  Your .svc file has "HumanResourceService.HRService", so the name attribute for the `<service>` element should match:

```
<service name="HumanResourceService.HRService">
```

Also, is this a RESTful service or SOAP?  I ask because you are using the `webHttpBinding` for your service, which is for REST.  If it's not, I suggest `basicHttpBinding` or `wsHttpBinding`.

If it is REST, then add this to the behavior section of your config file:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="webBehavior">
    <webHttp />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Comment: I changed my web.config to match the service name with it in .svc file,(I updated my post), but the problem exists yet(my servis is SOAP).

Comment: I, also upload another simple sample( default service template in VS2010) in (http://msanaei.persiangig.com/Masoud/TestService.rar/download) this sample has the same problem.